# Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 00:00:00 for dates

Tags: python, pandas

here is the first 10 lines of my file.

```
Year    Revenue
0   Jan-07  1757000
1   Feb-07  2052000
2   Mar-07  2747000
3   Apr-07  2308000
4   May-07  2289000
5   Jun-07  2322000
6   Jul-07  2310000
7   Aug-07  2049000
8   Sep-07  1862000
9   Oct-07  2006000
10  Nov-07  2061000
```

I started my code as follows:

````
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
%matplotlib inline
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
from pandas.plotting import autocorrelation_plot
import seaborn as sns

from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta```

I then imported my data set into the file 
```df=pd.read_csv(pathway.csv', sep=',',)

I wanted to see the data types of my file to see what I was working with. 
So I used  ```df.info``` to see what my datafile types were.
````

RangeIndex: 144 entries, 0 to 143
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Year                                       144 non-null object
Revenue from Sale of Recycled Materials    144 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 2.3+ K

```
Then I tried to translate the years into yyyy-mm-dd format by using this code but I error out  with OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-07 00:00:00
```

df.month = pd.to_datetime(df.month)
df.set_index('month', inplace=True)

```
I expect from my data set to change to 
0   2007-01-01 1757000
1  2007-02-01  2052000
2  2007-03-01  2747000
3  2007-04-01  2308000
4  2007-05-01  2289000
5  2007-06-01  2322000
......

once I complete this i will plot a time series graph, with $ on the y column and x being the date
```

Comment: Your DataFrame doesn't have a `month` column on input so I'd expect something quite different here... have you been trying other things and ended up with create a `month` column somehow and how'd you do that? That'd explain your error.

Comment: I set my columns to ```df.columns = ['month', 'value']``` . Does this not mean that I have the month column in my data frame now?

Comment: That sets the names of the columns... it doesn't do anything apart from that (but that'll already be set from reading the file)... how do you read the file?

Comment: ```df=pd.read_csv (the pathway to my link.csv', sep=',')```

Comment: Okay... so `df.columns` should be `Year` and the other one, right? What are you then trying to do?

Comment: in the file the columns names are Year and revenue from Sale of recycled Materials

Comment: I'm trying to change the  ```month value
0 Jan-07 1757000
1 Feb-07 2052000
2 Mar-07 2747000
3 Apr-07 2308000
4 May-07 2289000```   dates into yyyy-mm-dd format so that I can start creating a time series plot.

Comment: Let's get your question [edit]ed into shape... copy and paste the first 10 lines from the CSV file and put it in your Q as a code block - it's not likely anyone's going to follow a link and if it goes down, no one's going to know what it was later, then show the code you've already tried and then explain what it is you're trying to do and what you expect as output...  That shouldn't take too long and will go a long way towards making this an answerable question.

Comment: Even if I change anything to year I still get an error

Comment: People won't be able to help you until you [edit] your question into order as I've suggested...

Comment: I have tried to change it to your suggesstion @JonClements

Comment: Okay... so you're almost there with `to_datetime`, you need to specify a format in this case... so try: `df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Year, format='%b-%y')`...

Answer (score 0):

Fix your dates by adding whatever is missing? I'm guessing we can just make the day the first of the month..

Then convert them to datetimes

```
df["year"] = "01-" + df["year"]

df["year"] = pd.to_datetime(df["year"], format="%d-%b-%y")

df = df.set_index("year")
```